# Non-bold text to take the space of bold text

Tags: css

I am using CSS to style some radio buttons as tabs.  I would like the "selected" tab's font-weight to be bold.  Of course, this causes the size of the tab to increase, as the text takes up more space.  I would like to find a way to have the text go from bold to non-bold without the "tab" changing size

[image: Tab 1 selected]

[image: Tab 2 selected]

Short of setting a fixed width, is there a crafty and clean way of making the text take up the size of bold text without it actually being bold?

The only method I can think of would be to have the bold text exist (causing the text to exist twice in the HTML), but with `visibility: hidden`.

#### Markup:

```
<label class="tab active"><input type="radio" name="someTabs" value="someValueA" />Tab 1</label>
<label class="tab"><input type="radio" name="someTabs" value="someValueB" />Tab 2 (with longer text)</label>
```

#### Relevant CSS as it is now:

```
.tab {
  display: block;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  height: 2em;
  line-height: 2em;
  margin-right: 1px;
  padding: 0 2em;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  float: left;
}
.tab.active,
.tab:hover {
  font-weight: bold;
}
.tab input[type=radio] {
  display: none;
}
```

Comment: Would text-shadow work?

Comment: @zackt147, Interesting idea.  Not quite what I'm looking for (makes the text less-readable with shadow set to the same color), but we may end up using it (with a real shadow color) instead of bolding.  Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is also a solution using *ghost* elements. Simply use the same text with a bold style, which lies underneath the visible ares:

HTML:

```
<div class="link">
    <div class="text">Sample Text</div>
    <div class="ghost">Sample Text</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.link {
    border: 1px #000 solid;
    display: inline-block;
}

.link .ghost {
    color: transparent;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.link .text {
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
}

.link .text:hover {
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

Here is a [**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/adqqC/) to check it out!

The only caveat is that the visible text is not centered within the outer div. Maybe someone can pick up from here?!

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  This is effectively the same as I had proposed where the text visibility would be set to hidden.  While this will work, I was hoping to find a solution that didn't require doubling the text in the markup.  I will keep this idea in mind though.

Comment: A better solution would be to use CSS's `content` property paired with a pseudo element like in the linked duplicate

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/adqqC/8/ -- Improved the above fiddle, Got Text Centered, by removing the position: absolute, and instead using height 0 for ghost, make sure padding top and bottom for ghost also 0.

Answer (score 1):

What about css `letter-spacing`? The result will be near the desired one:

```
.tab
{
    letter-spacing: 1.5px;
}

.tab.active, .tab:hover 
{
    letter-spacing: normal;
}
```

[jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/N5y68/2/)

Comment: Good idea.  This will be a good option if there isn't a more direct method.